# Japanese Numerals to Arabic Numerals converter in Python

Tags: python, translation, machine-translation

Is there an open source library in Python which does Kanji Numeral to Arabic Numeral conversion/translation?

Input : 10億2千9百万
Output: 1,029,000,000

Input : 1億6,717万2,600
Output: 167,172,600

Input : 3,139百万
Output: 3,139,000,000

Japanese Numeral Systems : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_numerals

Web Based Converter : http://www.sljfaq.org/cgi/kanjinumbers.cgi

Comment: Note that 円 is the character for Yen (currency).

Comment: **EDIT:** My bad. I've removed that glyph from the example input lines.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
import kanjinums
kanjinums.kanji2num("五百十一")
```

After downloading and installing [kanjinums](http://ginstrom.com/scribbles/2009/04/28/converting-kanji-numbers-to-integers-with-python/), which is unfortunately not available through pip.

**EDIT:** This will only work for basic numbers, not the complex cases like mentioned.

With minor modifications this will actually work, for instance:

```
3139*kanjinums.kanji2num("百万")
3139000000
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately, that module only does simple dictionary lookup and is good for simple Kanji numerals but does not support complex conversion like the examples I mentioned.

Comment: Yes I am realizing that. Sorry! It appears I would need to be able to understand kanji a little better to provide any useful information.

Comment: you will need to write a function or class that converts your numbers using this, by replacing strings with expressions (as one way).

Answer (score 2):

This can actually be done relatively easy in a function:

```
def convert_kanji(self, zahl):
    japnumber = ("兆", "億",  "万")
    jap_factors = {
            "兆": 1000000000000,
            "億": 100000000,
            "万": 10000
            }

    #Define the variables
    converted_number = 0
    already_found = False
    found_kanji_previous = 0

    try: #If the number can be returned as an integer (i.e. no Kanji in it) -> do it
        return(int(zahl)) 
    except ValueError: #If not, disintegrate it
        for key in japnumber: #do it for every Kanji
            if key in zahl: #If it has been found in the original string:
                gef_kanji = zahl.find(key) #mark, which Kanji has been found
                if not already_found: #if it is the first kanji:
                    intermediate_step = int(zahl[:gef_kanji]) * jap_factors[key] #Convert the number in front of the Kanji with the appropriate factor
                    converted_number = intermediate_step
                    already_found = True
                    found_kanji_previous = gef_kanji
                else: #for sll other kanjis
                    intermediate_step = int(zahl[found_kanji_previous+1:gef_kanji]) * jap_factors[key]
                    converted_number = converted_number + intermediate_step #sum them up
                    found_kanji_previous = gef_kanji

        if len(zahl) > (found_kanji_previous+1):
            converted_number = converted_number + int(zahl[found_kanji_previous+1:])
        return converted_number
```

This is still relatively simple. It can only accept numbers in the form of 2314兆3424億3422万2342.

Also the code might be extremely bad, because this was actually my first program in a long long time. But it might be a good starting point for you.

I am actually currently working on a easy converter which will convert japanese numbers into easy to read western ones (e.g. converting 231億 to “23 billion 100 million”; it actually already does that). I guess there is much do be done, e.g. full-width characters, numbers completely in Kanji etc. If I have tackled all that, I might upload it similarily as kanjinums :D